# Is there a way to open the add in full screen programmatically?

Tags: iphone, iad

Is it possible to run full screen iAds in App.

In the Words with Friends app there seems to be a random timer which when it goes off it acts like the user clicked on the iAd.

Is there a way to open the add in full screen programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words with Friends uses ads by Greystripe. This isn't possible with iAds ads.

Comment: Thank you donkim for your instant reply.

Comment: ya, This answer is very much helpfull for me.. and i also started implementing greystripe.

Comment: I think what @zebulon meant was that you should accept more answers to your questions. You can do that by clicking on the outline of the checkmark next to an answer. I was encouraged to do this just a little while ago -- this helps in getting others to answer your questions, plus it's what StackOverflow is all about, as is the upvoting (or downvoting!) of answers/questions. Not to pimp my answer, of course... :)